# send email to client - custom module

Tags: magento2, email

Guys after a lot of research, I managed to create a module that sends an email to the store owner, but I also need him to send an email with the content to the customer. Does anyone know how I can change my controller so that it sends the content to the client as well?

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Controller\Index;

use Zend\Log\Filter\Timestamp;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_NAME = 'trans_email/ident_support/name';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_EMAIL = 'trans_email/ident_support/email';


    protected $_inlineTranslation;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_logLoggerInterface;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []

    ) {
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_logLoggerInterface = $loggerInterface;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        try {
            // Send Mail
            $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();

            $senderName = $post['name'];
            $senderEmail = $post['email'];

            $sender = [
                'name' => $senderName,
                'email' => $senderEmail
            ];

            $sentToEmail = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

            $sentToName = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);




            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => 'frontend',
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars([
                    'name'  => $post['name'],
                    'email'  => $post['email']
                ])
                ->setFromByScope($sender)
                ->addTo($sentToEmail, $sentToName)
                //->addTo('test@test.com', 'owner')
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess('sucess!');
            $this->_redirect('customemail/index/index');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder there is a method available

```
public function addCc($address, $name = '')
{
    $this->addAddressByType('cc', $address, $name);

    return $this;
}
```

Just add this line ->addCc("abc@gmail.com", "abc")

It will look like this

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => 'frontend',
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars([
                'name'  => $post['name'],
                'email'  => $post['email']
            ])
            ->setFromByScope($sender)
            ->addTo($sentToEmail, $sentToName)
            ->addCc("abc@gmail.com", "abc")
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: the code says that the addAddressByType method does not exist